# Script out entire SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to easily generate a script for an entire SQL Server instance?

I need..

- all databases
- all users
- all server objects
- all sql jobs

pretty much everything. I need this find out where a given string e.g "xxxxxx" has been used.

Comment: Server: No.  Database: yes. Sounds a bit like a backup set?

Comment: Doesn't RedGate have a tool for this?

Comment: yeah they do but it only searches within a specific database as far as i know

Answer (score 2):

How much of what you want to check *isn't* queryable via the [system catalogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx)?

- Databases: `select name from sys.databases`
- Roles/Users: `select name from sys.database_principals`
- Server Objects: `select name from sys.objects`

etc

Comment: @Mitch OP said 'i need this find out where a given string e.g "xxxxxx" has been used.'

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: this doesnt search the entire db server and server objects

Comment: It searches everything inside a database - repeat for each database on your server....